# Список UL в JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Не могу сообразить как соорудить `json` из `ul`.
Есть список такого типа:

```
<ul>
  <li data-id="1"><a>Родительский элемент списка 1</a>
     <ul>
       <li data-id="2">дочерний элемент списка 1</li>
       <li data-id="3">дочерний элемент списка 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-id="4">Родительский элемент списка 2</li>
  <li data-id="5">Родительский элемент списка 3</li>
</ul>
```

Задача: получить из этого `json hierarchical`:

```
[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2},{"id":3}]},{"id":4},{"id":5}]
```

Comment: Как уже пытались решить, что не получилось?

Answer (score 2):

У элементов есть свойство `children`, которое позволяет обращаться к потомкам.
Использовать стоит его.

```js
/**
 * Рекурсивно собираем все data-id с потомками
 *
 * @param {HTMLUListElement} ul   UL-Контейнер с данными
 * @param {Boolean}          json Вернуть собранный массив или его JSON-представление?
 *
 * @return {Array|String}
 */
function transform(ul, json = true) {
  let tree = [];
  
  /**
   * Наполнение дерева значениями
   *
   * @param {HTMLLIElement} e   LI-элемент с data-id
   * @param {Array}         ref Ссылка на дерево, куда добавлять свойства
   */
  function push(e, ref) {
    let pointer = { // Берём атрибут id элемента
      id: +e.dataset.id
    };
    
    if (e.childElementCount) { // Если есть потомки
      pointer.children = []; // Создаём свойство для них
      Array.from(e.children).forEach(i => { // Перебираем... хм... детей (по косточкам!)
        if (i.nodeName === 'UL') { // Если есть ещё один контейнер UL, перебираем его
          Array.from(i.children).forEach(e => {
            push(e, pointer.children); // Вызываем push на новых li, но ссылка на древо теперь - это массив children указателя
          });
        }
      });
    }

    ref.push(pointer);
  }

  // Проходимся по всем li переданного ul
  Array.from(ul.children).forEach(e => {
    push(e, tree);
  });
  
  return json ? JSON.stringify(tree) : tree;
}

console.info(transform(document.querySelector('ul')));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="1"><a>Родительский элемент списка 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li data-id="2">дочерний элемент списка 1</li>
      <li data-id="3">дочерний элемент списка 2</li>
      <li data-id="8">
        <ul>
          <li data-id="7">дочерний элемент списка 1</li>
          <li data-id="9">дочерний элемент списка 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-id="4">Родительский элемент списка 2</li>
  <li data-id="5">Родительский элемент списка 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Все хорошо и правильный json получается, но лишние children[]. Решается `if (e.childElementCount>1)`

Comment: @Владислав, нет, потомки есть только у тех, где есть вложенность, только сейчас просмотрел тщательно. Если `e.childElementCount` вернёт хоть одного потомка, будет массив `children`. Ваш `pull request` не найдёт потомка, если он один. Или Вам так и нужно?

Answer (score 2):

Можешь например иногда смотреть в сторону сервиса http://json2html.com/

Они например предлагают это сделать в таком виде:

```
{"<>":"ul","html":[
    {"<>":"li","data-id":"1","html":[
        {"<>":"a","html":"Родительский элемент списка 1"},
        {"<>":"ul","html":[
            {"<>":"li","data-id":"2","html":"дочерний элемент списка 1"},
            {"<>":"li","data-id":"3","html":"дочерний элемент списка 2"}
          ]}
      ]},
    {"<>":"li","data-id":"4","html":"Родительский элемент списка 2"},
    {"<>":"li","data-id":"5","html":"Родительский элемент списка 3"}
  ]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант с использованием [функции `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и рекурсии

```js
function transform(ul) {
  return [].map.call(ul.children, function(el) {
    var li = {
      id: el.dataset.id,
    };
    var ul = el.querySelector('ul');
    if (ul) {
      li.children = transform(ul);
    }
    return li;
  });
}

console.log(transform(document.querySelector('ul')));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="1"><a>Родительский элемент списка 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li data-id="2">дочерний элемент списка 1</li>
      <li data-id="3">дочерний элемент списка 2</li>
      <li data-id="8">
        <ul>
          <li data-id="7">дочерний элемент списка 1</li>
          <li data-id="9">дочерний элемент списка 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-id="4">Родительский элемент списка 2</li>
  <li data-id="5">Родительский элемент списка 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Использовал Ваш вариант. Только в конце функции `return JSON.stringify(li);`

Comment: @Владислав, да, можно и так, если нужна строка